# how to submit form on click of checkbox in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a form like this in Codeigniter :

```
<form id="myform" action="">
           <h3><?php echo $approv['title'];?></h3>
           <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="appro">
          </form>
```

I want to submit this on click of a checkbox. i m new to Codeigniter.please help.

Comment: You need to use `jQuery` or `javascript` for that

Answer (score 3):

Try using javascript function on click :

```
 <form id="myform" action="">
<h3><?php echo $approv['title'];?></h3>
<input type="checkbox" id="appro" value="1" name="appro">
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#appro").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    $("#myform").submit();
});
</script>
```